# Isn't postulating Spell-Out resurrecting the old notion of Surface Structure?

Tags: minimalism, government-and-binding

The key distinction, where Spell-Out is a *point* in the derivation rather than a true *level of representation* is still rather obscure to me.

Can you explain why Spell-Out is something different, rather than a different name for the same thing?